# Enable NetBIOS in Belkin Router

Tags: wireless-router, netbios

Is there any way I can enable NetBIOS in my Belkin router? My Router model Wireless 150N, hardware model F7D1301 v1

Comment: enable it to do what? your router does not provide services over SMB/NBT, so what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry about delay, I was asleep. " your router does not provide services over SMB/NBT" means what??

Comment: that there is not usually any point in enabling NetBIOS (NBT) on a router. please state what you want to do, and why you think enabling NBT on your router will help you do it.

Comment: My ISP uses netbios protocol in there file sharing service. The router by default forward netbios address, so I can't access file sharing service using router, neither on Linux. So I am asking is there a way I can forward my netbios address through router.

Comment: NBT uses tcp\135,138, and 445, as well as udp\137, 139, so you can allow those ports through your firewall, but it is a very very bad idea. this does not sound legitimate.